# what is the pytorch equivalent of a tensorflow linear regression?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, pytorch, regression

I am learning pytorch, that to do a basic linear regression on this data created this way here:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression

x, y = make_regression(n_samples=100, n_features=1, noise=15, random_state=42)
y = y.reshape(-1, 1)
print(x.shape, y.shape)

plt.scatter(x, y)
```

I know that using tensorflow this code can solve:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='linear', input_shape=(x.shape[1], )))

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.05), loss='mse')

hist = model.fit(x, y, epochs=15, verbose=0)
```

but I need to know what the pytorch equivalent would be like, what I tried to do was this:

```
# Model Class
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.linear = nn.Linear(1,1)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.linear(x)
        return x
    
    def predict(self, x):
        return self.forward(x)
    
model = Net()

loss_fn = F.mse_loss
opt = torch.optim.SGD(modelo.parameters(), lr=0.05)

# Funcao para treinar
def fit(num_epochs, model, loss_fn, opt, train_dl):
    
    
    # Repeat for given number of epochs
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        
        # Train with batches of data
        for xb, yb in train_dl:
            
            # 1. Generate predictions
            pred = model(xb)
            
            # 2. Calculate Loss
            loss = loss_fn(pred, yb)
            
            # 3. Campute gradients
            loss.backward()
            
            # 4. Update parameters using gradients
            opt.step()
            
            # 5. Reset the gradients to zero
            opt.zero_grad()
            
        # Print the progress
        if (epoch+1) % 10 == 0:
            print('Epoch [{}/{}], Loss: {:.4f}'.format(epoch+1, num_epochs, loss.item()))

# Training
fit(200, model, loss_fn, opt, data_loader)
```

But the model doesn't learn anything, I don't know what I can do anymore.

The input/output dimensions is (1/1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Dataset

First of all, you should define [`torch.utils.data.Dataset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Dataset)

```
import torch
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression


class RegressionDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        data = make_regression(n_samples=100, n_features=1, noise=0.1, random_state=42)
        self.x = torch.from_numpy(data[0]).float()
        self.y = torch.from_numpy(data[1]).float()

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.x)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.x[index], self.y[index]
```

It converts `numpy` data to PyTorch's `tensor` inside `__init__` and converts data to `float` (`numpy` has `double` by default while PyTorch's default is `float` in order to use less memory).

Apart from that it will simply return `tuple` of features and respective regression targets.

### Fit

Almost there, but you have to flatten output from the model (described below). `torch.nn.Linear` will return tensors of shape `(batch, 1)` while your targets are of shape `(batch,)`. `flatten()` will remove unnecessary `1` dimension.

```
# 2. Calculate Loss
loss = criterion(pred.flatten(), yb)
```

### Model

That is all you need actually:

```
model = torch.nn.Linear(1, 1)
```

Any layer can be called directly, no need for `forward` and inheritance for simple models.

### Calling

The rest is almost okay, you just have to create [`torch.utils.data.DataLoader`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader) and pass instance of our dataset. What `DataLoader` does is it issues `__getitem__` of `dataset` multiple times and creates a batch of specified size (there is some other funny business, but that's the idea):

```
dataset = RegressionDataset()
dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=32)
model = torch.nn.Linear(1, 1)
criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=3e-4)

fit(5000, model, criterion, optimizer, dataloader)
```

Also notice I've used `torch.nn.MSELoss()`, as we are passing object it looks better than function in this case.

### Whole code

To make it easier:

```
import torch
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression


class RegressionDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        data = make_regression(n_samples=100, n_features=1, noise=0.1, random_state=42)
        self.x = torch.from_numpy(data[0]).float()
        self.y = torch.from_numpy(data[1]).float()

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.x)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.x[index], self.y[index]


# Funcao para treinar
def fit(num_epochs, model, criterion, optimizer, train_dl):
    # Repeat for given number of epochs
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):

        # Train with batches of data
        for xb, yb in train_dl:

            # 1. Generate predictions
            pred = model(xb)

            # 2. Calculate Loss
            loss = criterion(pred.flatten(), yb)

            # 3. Compute gradients
            loss.backward()

            # 4. Update parameters using gradients
            optimizer.step()

            # 5. Reset the gradients to zero
            optimizer.zero_grad()

        # Print the progress
        if (epoch + 1) % 10 == 0:
            print(
                "Epoch [{}/{}], Loss: {:.4f}".format(epoch + 1, num_epochs, loss.item())
            )


dataset = RegressionDataset()
dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=32)
model = torch.nn.Linear(1, 1)
criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=3e-4)

fit(5000, model, criterion, optimizer, dataloader)
```

You should get around `0.053` loss or so, vary `noise` or other params for harder/easier regression task.

Comment: @manynothing While thank you is natural, here we thank with upvotes and accepting answer which you already did (such comments generate unnecessary noise). Glad I could help, welcome to StackOverflow! :)